# Why am I getting TypeError list indices must be integers or slices , not str while passing arguments to multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement multiprocesssing for image processing from multiple folders, when I use multiprocessing library I'm trying to pass multiple arguments to the pool function but Im getting type error, my code is as below

```
def augment(args):
       imgs = args[0]
       bpath = args[1]
       dictcount = args[2]
       for img in imgs:
           cv2.imread(img)
def main():
       basepath = 'some path'
       count_dict = {some dict}
       allImagepaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(basepath))
       procs = no_cores if no_cores > 0 else cpu_count()
       procids = list(range(0,procs))
       noImgsproc = len(allImagepaths) /float(procs)
       noImgsproc = int(np.ceil(noImgsproc))
       chunkpaths = list(chunk(allImagepaths,noImgsproc))
       payloads = [ ]
       for (i,imgpaths) in enumberate(chunkpaths):
            data = {"id":i,"input_paths":imgpaths}
            payloads.append(data)
       pool = Pool(processes = procs)
       pool.map(augment,[[payloads,basepath,count_dict]])
```

when I run this I get error as below

> File "aug_imgs.pylin 306, in main
> pool.map(augment,[[payloads,basepath,count_dict]])
>
> File
> "C:\Users\rob\anaconda3\envs\retinanet\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 364, in map                           return
> self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
> File
> "C:\Users\rob\anaconda3\envs\retinanet\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 771, in get                           raise self._value
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

but if I pass only one argument with a function code runs perfectly without error there I'm passing as imgs = args in augment()
as below

pool.map(augment,payloads)

what am I doing wrong any help solving this will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You're using `pool.map()` incorrectly. As I've said in your other question, you have to pass in the collection of images over which you want the process pool to iterate.

Comment: Also, why are passing in base_path and count_dict if they aren't used inside `augment()`?

Comment: hey I tried your answer I couldn't make it to work I ran into series of errors so I followed this article https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/09/multiprocessing-with-opencv-and-python/ I thought of trying it

Comment: I'm using base_path and count_dict but I didn't show it in the code as the length is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down your processing function to work on a single image, then pass the collection of images to the process pool. You can set additional constant parameters by using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```py
from functools import partial

def augment(base_path, count_dict, image):
    # do something with base_path & count_dict
    cv2.imread(image)

def main():
    # assuming base_path and count_dict are defined here
    partial_augment = partial(augment, base_path, count_dict)
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(partial_augment, images)
```

Comment: It worked thanks but I see only two processes going on simultaneously which  is two folders at a time ,I've 4 cores of cpu why can't I run all the folders simultaneously?

Comment: It shouldn't run folders in parallel but images, unless you've changed the code. You can check the output of `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`

Comment: I used same code mentioned in this question, does it works??

Comment: @xionxavier you have to change your code with what I gave you above: the `augment` function works on a single image and you pass the list of images to `pool.map()`. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes I tried I got some error , please check that question I've updated it with the implementation and error